# tabularx makes an unwanted line break

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx

As the title says, Tabluarx makes me an unwanted line break when I fill only one page in a table.

In the specific context, this is a list of pros and cons.

```
\documentclass[%
    fontsize=11pt, 
    twoside=off
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[tablewithout, figurewithout]{caption}

%tabelles
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{X<{\vspace{4pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}} 
%original: \newcolumntype{M}{X<{\vspace{4pt}}}
%one of both I **have** to use
 
%font
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
    \fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ M{1} | M{1} }
        \textbf{Vorteile}& \textbf{Nachteile}\\
        \hline
        + einfache, leicht nachvollziehbare Funktionsweise & - hoher Wartungsaufwand, regelmäßiger Ölwechsel \\ 
        + Signalleitung über die Tragkonstruktion möglich & - empfindlich für mechanische Beschädigung \\
        + nur geringer Strombedarf für die Aufzeichnung & - sehr anfällig für Belegung mit Treibzeug, Kraut \\
        + langlebig & - Blockade durch Sandkörner, Vereisung möglich\\
        & - großer zeitlicher Aufwand bei Hochwasser\\%
        & - Beeinflussung durch Schiffstoß und Eis\\%
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Vor- und Nachteile des Messflügels}
    \label{Pro/Con Messflügel Einzelmesspunkt}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to stop that?

*An unrelated question: Is there an easy way to replace your body text with lorem Ipsum?*

Comment: please provide an example that shows the problem. the code posted has no `\begin{document}` and no definition of `M`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle added the missing code. But isn't the picture enough of an example?

Comment: no, not if you want anyone to debug the issue and test answers. How could anyone guess why some undefined column type has some space shown in th image, thanks for adding now

Comment: So the problem was the code, not the pic?

Comment: `\newcolumntype{M}[1]{X<{\vspace{4pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}}` is _very_ weird you change the with of (just) the last paragraph in each cell, leaving other paragraphs unchanged

Comment: If you use a normal `X` the problem does not appear.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Happy year David. I have used X.

Comment: The problem is that I have to use the M. It's slightly different from the template I'm supposed to use (I inserted it into the code) and it was a struggle to get it accepted by the supervisor.

But for me, it makes no difference which M I use.

Comment: If you have to use `M` then you have to have broken output. That is a social problem not a technical one. The definition makes no sense, but if a person in authority is telling you to use it, you have to do what you have to do. Also note your entire issue is about code that you did not show in the initial version of the question.

Comment: As for your unrelated question: `\usepackage{lipsum}`, and then `\lipsum[n-m]` to print paragraphs n through m

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to recommend that you rearrange the table's contents as follows:

1. the contents of both columns should be organized as separate list-like environments,
2. don't use vertical rules, but well-spaced horizontal rules such as `\midrule` (provided by the `booktabs` package),
3. use the `enumitem` package to customize the appearance of the list-like enviroments, including the vertical separation between items, and
4. do away with instructions such as `\fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont`, `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}`; and `\vspace{4pt}` as they are very clumsy and are (essentially) asking for trouble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,twoside=off]{scrbook}

\usepackage[tablewithout, figurewithout]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%tabelles
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} 
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X} % suppress justification

\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} % are you sure you need the 'scaled' option?
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{enumitem} % for \newlist and \setlist macros
\newlist{myitemize}{itemize}{1} % create a bespoke list-like env.
\setlist[myitemize]{label=\textbullet, left=0pt,
     itemsep=1ex, % set as needed/desired
     before={\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}},
     after={\end{minipage}}}
     
\usepackage{booktabs} % for '\midrule' macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\footnotesize % instead of '\fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont'
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} LL @{}} % note: no vertical rule
\textbf{Vorteile} & \textbf{Nachteile} \\
\midrule
\begin{myitemize}
\item Einfache, leicht nachvollziehbare Funktionsweise 
\item Signalleitung über die Tragkonstruktion möglich 
\item Nur geringer Strombedarf für die Aufzeichnung 
\item Langlebig
\end{myitemize}
&
\begin{myitemize}
\item Hoher Wartungsaufwand, regelmäßiger Ölwechsel
\item Empfindlich für mechanische Beschädigung
\item Sehr anfällig für Belegung mit Treibzeug, Kraut
\item Blockade durch Sandkörner, Vereisung möglich
\item Großer zeitlicher Aufwand bei Hochwasser
\item Beeinflussung durch Schiffstoß und Eis
\end{myitemize}\\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Vor- und Nachteile des Messflügels}
\label{Pro/Con_Messflügel_Einzelmesspunkt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Mico, that looks pretty good. Is there a way to change the dots to + and -? Regarding your Question about the "scaled". I have no idea it is one of the things I have to use.

Comment: @FloB - I would NOT use `+` and `-` symbols as labels for list items. They may look cute at first; however, they'll quickly start to look like "too cute for their own good" -- and thus start to look embarassing. If you absolutely, positively *must* use `+` and `-` instead of `\textbullet`, I would suggest you (a) create two separte list-like environments called, say, `myitemizeplus` and `myitemizeminus` and (b) write `label=$+$` and `label=$-$` instead of `label=\textbullet` inside the respective `\setlist` directives.

Comment: good point. I won't use it. Is there a difference between `\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}` and `\usepackage{tabularx}` and do I have to state both?

Comment: @FloB - The `ragged2e` package provides the `\RaggedRight` macro, which is used in the definition of the `L` column type.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure where you found `X<{\vspace{4pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}`, but it's really wrong under many respects.

The `\hsize` setup should be done at the beginning, not at the end. And `\vspace{4pt}` is doing damage.

#### Example with `\vspace{4pt}` at the end

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt, 
  twoside=off
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[tablewithout, figurewithout]{caption}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X<{\vspace{4pt}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ M{1} | M{1} }
  \textbf{Vorteile}& \textbf{Nachteile}\\
  \hline
  + einfache, leicht nachvollziehbare Funktionsweise &
  - hoher Wartungsaufwand, regelmäßiger Ölwechsel \\ 
  + Signalleitung über die Tragkonstruktion möglich &
  - empfindlich für mechanische Beschädigung \\
  + nur geringer Strombedarf für die Aufzeichnung &
  - sehr anfällig für Belegung mit Treibzeug, Kraut \\
  + langlebig &
  - Blockade durch Sandkörner, Vereisung möglich \\
  &
  - großer zeitlicher Aufwand bei Hochwasser \\
  &
  - Beeinflussung durch Schiffstoß und Eis \\
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Vor- und Nachteile des Messflügels}
\label{Pro/Con Messflügel Einzelmesspunkt}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Example without `\vspace{4pt}` at the end

```
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt, 
  twoside=off
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[tablewithout, figurewithout]{caption}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.8}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htp]

\fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ M{1} | M{1} }
  \textbf{Vorteile}& \textbf{Nachteile}\\
  \hline
  + einfache, leicht nachvollziehbare Funktionsweise &
  - hoher Wartungsaufwand, regelmäßiger Ölwechsel \\ 
  + Signalleitung über die Tragkonstruktion möglich &
  - empfindlich für mechanische Beschädigung \\
  + nur geringer Strombedarf für die Aufzeichnung &
  - sehr anfällig für Belegung mit Treibzeug, Kraut \\
  + langlebig &
  - Blockade durch Sandkörner, Vereisung möglich \\
  &
  - großer zeitlicher Aufwand bei Hochwasser \\
  &
  - Beeinflussung durch Schiffstoß und Eis \\
\end{tabularx}

\caption{Vor- und Nachteile des Messflügels}
\label{Pro/Con Messflügel Einzelmesspunkt}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Why the difference?

Because `\vspace{4pt}` is inserted after the strut added at the end of the cell and the effect is completely unpredictable.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation of why the `\vspace{4pt}` approach is, ahem, highly problematic.

Answer (score 3):

To center the text vertically in each cell, you can use the `m` column type from the `array` package. Also, for better centering, you can use the `X` column type from the `tabularx` package.

PS: The font of your figure is an Arial (I think).

```
\documentclass[%
    fontsize=11pt, 
    twoside=off
]{scrbook}
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[tablewithout, figurewithout]{caption}
\usepackage{array} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
    \fontsize{9pt}{13pt}\selectfont
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X | X }
        \textbf{Vorteile} & \textbf{Nachteile} \\
        \hline
        + einfache, leicht nachvollziehbare Funktionsweise & - hoher Wartungsaufwand, regelmäßiger Ölwechsel \\ 
        + Signalleitung über die Tragkonstruktion möglich & - empfindlich für mechanische Beschädigung \\
        + nur geringer Strombedarf für die Aufzeichnung & - sehr anfällig für Belegung mit Treibzeug, Kraut \\
        + langlebig & - Blockade durch Sandkörner, Vereisung möglich\\
        & - großer zeitlicher Aufwand bei Hochwasser\\
        & - Beeinflussung durch Schiffstoß und Eis\\
    \end{tabularx}
    \caption{Vor- und Nachteile des Messflügels}
    \label{Pro/Con Messflügel Einzelmesspunkt}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, I had forgotten some code (e.g. the font). Sadly the M is something I have to use since it is a text for the University

Comment: @FloB It gave me an error with the M.

Comment: @FloB do not use `M` as defined it is simply wrong.

Comment: If you tell me how I get the \vspace{4pt} for every column I would love to.

Comment: @FloB `\addtolength\extrarowheight{4pt}`